# React PropTypes - shape with numbers as keys

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to specify the PropTypes for one of my React components and have run into some problems. The object I'm trying to describe is going to look like this (the array will contain multiple objects):

```
rounds: {
  1: [
       {
         date: 1429354800000,
         arena: 'Arena name',
         scoreHome: 3,
         scoreAway: 2,
         teamHome: 'Home team name',
         teamAway: 'Away team name',
         spectators: 10
       }
     ]
}
```

I will not know in advance how many rounds there will be. So I could end up with

```
rounds: { 1: [..], 2: [..], 3: [..] }
```

This is what I currently have (not working):

```
RoundsTable.propTypes = {
  rounds: PropTypes.shape({
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      date: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      arena: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      scoreHome: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      scoreAway: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      teamHome: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      teamAway: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      spectators: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }).isRequired).isRequired
  }).isRequired
}
```

I'm not sure how to specify the number that contains the array of objects. Is it a data design problem on my side or is there a simple solution for specifying these kinds of props?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an object with numbered keys, rather than an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a data design problem. You are using an `Object` as an array. For example, this would work if you changed your data accordingly:

```
RoundsTable.propTypes = {
  rounds: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      date: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      arena: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      scoreHome: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      scoreAway: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      teamHome: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      teamAway: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      spectators: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }).isRequired).isRequired
}
```

The data would look like this:

```
rounds: [
       {
         date: 1429354800000,
         arena: 'Arena name',
         scoreHome: 3,
         scoreAway: 2,
         teamHome: 'Home team name',
         teamAway: 'Away team name',
         spectators: 10
       },
       {...}
]
```

You lose the indexes, but arrays already have those. If you wanted more map-like functionality, you would need to decide what kind of map to use and base your PropTypes on that. Javascript does not have native maps, though people very often use `Object` for the same purpose, that has a number of limitations, such as the one you have run into.

Comment: This solved my problems. Still curious about if its possible to describe my initial structure using PropTypes though. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with your initial structure is that you are not using `{}` correctly. That is an object literal, not a map, and you are using it as a map. The test you should make in your head is: Can I define all the keys ahead of time? If not, then you want an array or a map (such as the ES6 `Map` class). In your case there's no limit to the number of rounds, so you cannot use an Object literal. The reason you did this is probably because you sometimes saw code that "abused" Javascript Objects as map-likes, because they are so flexible. Does that make sense?

Comment: this is not a good answer. not all ints are indexes. I have the same issue where my keys could be: 126, 8654, 65683. this is not for an array but a dictionary key

Comment: @DeGoltz You can use an [ES6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The Javascript `Object` was not designed to be used as a dictionary. Its keys were designed to only be strings, and even then it has many problems when you use them like a map.

Comment: @EugeneZ there is still an issue with objects with dynamic keys (string or int). If the values have a fixed structure, you would want to enforce that and not just use PropTypes.object. for example when you get it as-is from an API