# Ensuring each element of an array conforms to a custom shape in React (again)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

The error I'm trying to get past is: `Warning: Failed prop type: checker is not a function`

I have a very similar to the question posted here: 
[Ensuring each element of an array property conforms to custom shape in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424852/ensuring-each-element-of-an-array-property-conforms-to-custom-shape-in-react)

[image: Here is the object I'm trying to validate]

The object that I'm trying to add is complicated and I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Here is what I've tried:

```
Card.propTypes = {
  node: shape({
    images: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.shape({
      entity: PropTypes.shape({
        image: PropTypes.shape({
          derivative: PropTypes.shape({
            url: PropTypes.string,
          }),
        }),
      }),
      mid: PropTypes.number,
    }))),
    title: PropTypes.string,
    body: {
      value: PropTypes.string,
    },
  }).isRequired,
  ctaHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deleteHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Seems that this issue is similar too - numbers as keys.
[React PropTypes - shape with numbers as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358148/react-proptypes-shape-with-numbers-as-keys)

Also tried this:

```
Card.propTypes = {
  node: PropTypes.shape({
    author: PropTypes.string,
    body: {
      value: PropTypes.string,
    },
    images: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      entity: PropTypes.shape({
        image: PropTypes.shape({
          derivative: PropTypes.shape({
            url: PropTypes.string,
          }),
        }),
      }),
      mid: PropTypes.number,
    })),
    nid: PropTypes.number,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    uuid: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  ctaHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deleteHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

I also tried to map my model object, returned from my GraphQL server, to something a little less complicated.

```
  let nodes = result.nodes.entities.map(node => { 
    const newNode = {...node};
    newNode.images = newNode.images.map(image => {
      return {url: image.entity.image.derivative.url, mid: image.mid};
    })
    return newNode;
  });
  this.setState({
    nodes: nodes
  });
```

which should seemingly give me the following signature:

```
Card.propTypes = {
  node: PropTypes.shape({
    author: PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string,
    }),
    body: {
      value: PropTypes.string,
    },
    images: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      url: PropTypes.string,
      mid: PropTypes.number,
    })),
    nid: PropTypes.number,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    uuid: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  ctaHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deleteHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error: 
`Failed prop type: checker is not a function
          in Card`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Warning: Failed prop type: checker is not a function` it is probably typo in your `propTypes` declaration. That is why it show it in this case, you have:

```
body: {
    value: PropTypes.string,
},
```

It should be

```
body: PropTypes.shape({
 value: PropTypes.string,
}),
```